# How to define a template class template friend function which one of its parameters is a dependent name outside the template class body?

Tags: c++, templates, friend-function

Hello I have this program:

I want to create a generic class `Add` that works as a functor, I intend to overload the stream I/O operators to works with it.

The thing is that I want the stream operators `<< >>` to be generic too, so that there stream parameter can be an `std::istream` or `std::ifstream` and so on. This applies to the insertion operator too.

The reason I do this is that if I write `std::cout << Add<int>{}` will prints it on the screen and if I do: `ofstream("data.txt") >> Add<int>{};` will write it to the file.

- I know an `ifstream` is an `istream` but I intend to use maybe other types that has their I/O operators doing another stuff.

  ```
    template <typename T>
    class Add
    {
        T operator()(T const& a, T const& b){return a + b;}

        template <typename STREAM_IN>
        friend STREAM_IN& operator >> (STREAM_IN& in, Add<T>& a){ in >> a.x; return in;}

        template <typename STREAM_OUT>
        friend STREAM_OUT& operator << (STREAM_OUT& out, Add<T> const& a){ out << a.x; return out;}

        int x = 89;
    };

    //template <typename T>
    //template <typename STREAM_IN>
    //STREAM_IN& operator >> (STREAM_IN& in, Add<T>& a)
    //{
    //    return in >> a.x;
    //}


    int main()
    {

        Add<long> a;
        std::ifstream in("data.txt");
        in >> a;
        std::cout << a << '\n';
        in.close();
        a.x += 7;
        std::ofstream out("data.txt");
        out << a;


        std::cout << "\ndone!\n";
    }
  ```
- The problem: How can I defined `>>` and `<<` outside the template class body?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? I simply defined two overloaded operators using templates for both the stream and the template type of Add. Since `Add` is a struct and not a class you shouldn't need to use friend functions.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class Add
{
    T operator()(T const& a, T const& b){return a + b;}

    template <typename STREAM, typename T2>
    friend STREAM& operator>>(STREAM& stream, Add<T2>& add);

    template <typename STREAM, typename T2>
    friend STREAM& operator<<(STREAM& stream, const Add<T2>& add);

    int x = 89;

public:
// in order to make the main function compile (not used by the operators)
    void add7() { x += 7; }
};

template <typename STREAM, typename T>
STREAM& operator>>(STREAM& stream, Add<T>& add) {
    stream >> add.x;
    return stream;
}

template <typename STREAM, typename T>
STREAM& operator<<(STREAM& stream, const Add<T>& add) {
    stream << add.x;
    return stream;
}

int main()
{

    Add<long> a;
    std::ifstream in("data.txt");
    in >> a;
    std::cout << a << '\n';
    in.close();
    a.add7();
    std::ofstream out("data.txt");
    out << a;


    std::cout << "\ndone!\n";
}
```

This part tells the compiler that this class is a friend to a function named `operator>>` that takes any type as first parameter and a class ``` And`` of template type ``` T```.

```
template <typename STREAM, typename T2>
friend STREAM& operator>>(STREAM& stream, Add<T2>& add);
```

And this part defines the body of the function.

```
template <typename STREAM, typename T>
STREAM& operator>>(STREAM& stream, Add<T>& add) {
    stream >> add.x;
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you didn't declare the operators as friends of the class. I've edited it from `struct` to `class`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it! I edited my post to address this issue!

Comment: If you want to ping the OP, you should use @, otherwise they may not see the comment.

Comment: @Maestro Does this answer your question? If it does, can you mark it as answered to close this issue? Thanks. (@cigien too :-))